# BLOB field returns null JSON

Tags: php, json

I am saving my images directly in the database (Yes I have read about that and know it's better to save the path to the image). 
The problem is selecting the image field which is a blob returns NULLto my JSON. I have alot read quite a few stackoverflow links of the same query but still not a clear explanation/ answer received has been able to help me.
I have encoded using base_64 but when doing so nothing is showed on the webpage.

Would appreciate if I could be pointed in the correct direction.

This is part of my code:

```
header("Content-Type:application/json");
//select query



$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}


    if (!empty($rows))
        {       
            $encode = array("StudentsList" => $rows);        
            //$json_response=json_encode($encode);
            $json_response=base64_encode($encode);
                    echo $json_response;
                    echo json_last_error(); //Returns 0
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need the json data
please use json_encode

example

```
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

and also read php manual

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: I am aware of this, however my image field is null when json_encode is used as stated in the question

Comment: so as I understand without json_ensode
you are getting base64 encoded image. right?
if so.
you can send your base64 image with json and decode it with js 
here is the library
https://github.com/dankogai/js-base64

Comment: no sir, with the current code I have posted. nothing is returned/posted. except 0 from my error checking

Comment: ok.
so in the firs please use base64_decode not encode
becouse in blob it is encoded..
also please decode received image data
not your own created array...

after base64_decode create array and encode it with json_encode
and the last step
send your json data where you want...